# Gap between 6" dia wall thimble & 6" hvac pipe

Tags: hvac, insulation, ventilation, chimney

I bought a 6" dia aluminum wall thimble to vent my 6" dia hvac steel exhaust pipe through to the outside. However, the diameter of the 6" thimble is actually 6 3/4". How do I effectively insulate the gap?
Thanks
  [image: wall thimble![6"dia hvac pipe]

Answer (score 2):

B-vent is what should be used for exhausting gas appliances and most likely why you have a gap in a 6" escussion with a 6" pipe in it. Notice the ID and OD for B-vent. If its just an air handler for a bath fan use a flapper vent.

[image]

AMPG's [PDF](http://www.ameri-vent.com/files/assets/files/1366997178_Catalog--TypeBVent.pdf)

Now you can fill the new 1/8~1/4" gap with an approved high temp caulk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pack it carefully with rock wool or fiberglass batting. DO NOT permit the two dissimilar metals to contact each other where there's any chance of moisture getting into the contact area, or you'll get galvanic corrosion at the junction, which can lead to leakage and exhaust gases getting back into the structure.